# What is the current directory for loading source file in IronScheme?

Tags: scheme, ironscheme

Is there any similar command such as `cd`, `pwd` which operate on current working directory in IronScheme?  I want to get the directory which is used by `(load "source.ss")`.

Besides, since IronScheme is a standard Scheme, I think the function works in other Scheme could also work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a not standard Scheme procedure, but in IronScheme you can do (one of) the following:

```
> (import (ironscheme environment))
> (current-directory) ; same as the present working dir
"C:\\Program Files\\IronScheme"
> (application-directory) ; where the IronScheme exe lives
"C:\\Program Files\\IronScheme"
>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Besides, can I add a directory to the search path of (load "") if it exists?